# Symfony UX chart does not show chart in easyadmin

Tags: php, symfony, chart.js, easyadmin, symfonyux

I have a problem with displaying a chart in easyadmin. It does show up in the HTML as shown below.

[image: chart not showing]

```
<canvas data-controller="symfony--ux-chartjs--chart" data-symfony--ux-chartjs--chart-view-value="{&quot;type&quot;:&quot;line&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:{&quot;labels&quot;:[&quot;January&quot;,&quot;February&quot;,&quot;March&quot;,&quot;April&quot;,&quot;May&quot;,&quot;June&quot;,&quot;July&quot;],&quot;datasets&quot;:[{&quot;label&quot;:&quot;My First dataset&quot;,&quot;backgroundColor&quot;:&quot;rgb(0, 0, 0)&quot;,&quot;borderColor&quot;:&quot;rgb(0, 0, 0)&quot;,&quot;data&quot;:[0,10,5,2,20,30,45]}]},&quot;options&quot;:{&quot;scales&quot;:{&quot;y&quot;:{&quot;suggestedMin&quot;:0,&quot;suggestedMax&quot;:100}}}}"></canvas>
```

My controller looks like this:

dashboardController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Product;
use App\Entity\ProductCategory;
use App\Entity\ProductImage;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Assets;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Dashboard;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\MenuItem;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractDashboardController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\UX\Chartjs\Builder\ChartBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\UX\Chartjs\Model\Chart;

class DashboardController extends AbstractDashboardController
{

    public function __construct( private ChartBuilderInterface $chartBuilder,) {

    }
    public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return parent::configureAssets()
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('app');

    }

    #[Route('/admin', name: 'admin')]
    public function index(): Response
    {

        return $this->render('admin/dashboard.html.twig', [
            'chart' => $this->createChart()]);
    }
    private function createChart(): Chart
    {
        $chart = $this->chartBuilder->createChart(Chart::TYPE_LINE);
        $chart->setData([
            'labels' => ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
            'datasets' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'My First dataset',
                    'backgroundColor' => 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                    'borderColor' => 'rgb(0, 0, 0)',
                    'data' => [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $chart->setOptions([
            'scales' => [
                'y' => [
                    'suggestedMin' => 0,
                    'suggestedMax' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        return $chart;
    }


    public function configureDashboard(): Dashboard
    {
        return Dashboard::new()
            ->setTitle('Dashboard');

    }

    public function configureMenuItems(): iterable
    {
        yield MenuItem::linkToDashboard('Dashboard', 'fa fa-home');
        yield MenuItem::section('Products');
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Product', 'fas fa-box', Product::class);
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Product images', 'fas fa-images', ProductImage::class);
        yield MenuItem::linkToCrud('Product category', 'fas fa-boxes-stacked', ProductCategory::class);
    }

}
```

The twig file does look this
dashboard.html.twig

```
{% extends '@!EasyAdmin/page/content.html.twig' %}
{% block page_title %}
    Dashboard
{% endblock %}
{% block main %}
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
            {{ render_chart(chart) }}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

My webpack.config.js is this

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or subdirectory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // enables the Symfony UX Stimulus bridge (used in assets/bootstrap.js)
    .enableStimulusBridge('./assets/controllers.json')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()

    /*
     * FEATURE CONFIG
     *
     * Enable & configure other features below. For a full
     * list of features, see:
     * https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html#adding-more-features
     */
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())

    // configure Babel
    // .configureBabel((config) => {
    //     config.plugins.push('@babel/a-babel-plugin');
    // })

    // enables and configure @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    // enables Sass/SCSS support
    //.enableSassLoader()

    // uncomment if you use TypeScript
    //.enableTypeScriptLoader()

    // uncomment if you use React
    //.enableReactPreset()

    // uncomment to get integrity="..." attributes on your script & link tags
    // requires WebpackEncoreBundle 1.4 or higher
    //.enableIntegrityHashes(Encore.isProduction())

    // uncomment if you're having problems with a jQuery plugin
    //.autoProvidejQuery()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

I got an error in the console since I added the following code:

```
 public function configureAssets(): Assets
    {
        return parent::configureAssets()
            ->addWebpackEncoreEntry('app');

    }
```

I added that part of code because I thought this would fix the problem of not showing the graph. Before I added the code there where no errors in the console but after I added the code these errors came up. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image: error of the console]

I use Symfony 6.1 and easyadmin 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it could not access the files so I edited the entrypoints.json to the correct paths and this fixed it.